# Rest Webservice Java File Upload with return message

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I am looking to find a problem to a solution that we are currently facing.

The requirement is that I want to develop a REST web-service that takes in user credentials and authenticates to the server and then upload the file to the server and returns a SUCCESS or FAILURE message.

So the REST webservice will be a POST but I want to return back the SUCCESS/ERROR message, and I know that is a bad design for a REST webservice. Is there an alternative way that I can approach this problem?

Can you let me know if what I thinking in the right way or do I need to take the SOAP route?

Comment: Use PUT for uploads. Throw an Exception and use an ExceptionMapper to indicate that an error has occured. Pass credentials in http headers (e.g basic auth, kerberos token or whatever your container supports)

Comment: Ok, is there a reason to use PUT? and also another thing I want to do in the response was to return back the checksum of the file that has been uploaded so that I can check the integrity. Can I send back an Xml or a JSON?

Comment: Http PUT is originally intended for file uploads, so it makes sense to use it there? Also, wouldn't it make much more sense to send checksum with the file as url parameter and check integrity on receiving side? Better yet, use ssl and forget about checking integrity.